# Collection to exclude array items in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure data factory we have Collections like:

```
intersection([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10],[6, 8, 1, 2])
```

whic returns `[1, 2]`

I'm looking for opposite to intersection. For given two arrays, it should return elements which are not present in first array.

```
Ex: If we pass two arrays, 
    Array a: [1,2,3,4,5]
    Array b: [1,2,3]

Ouput: [4,5]
```

One way is to add two **lookup** activites resulting two arrays and **Foreach** of item in first array, if not present in second item array execute another activity.

Is there any better way to do in Azure Data factory?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intersection` works with arrays.  If you have two arrays (Array being a native Azure Data Factory type) then I don't think Lookup will work as it works with datasets?  It's a shame Azure Data Factory (ADF v2) does not have the complement to `union` and `intersection` in terms of set operations which might be `complement` or `except` or `minus`.

However you can work around this using a `for each` loop and an `if` condition.  For example, I have an ADF v2 pipeline with two array parameters like this:

[image: ADF pipeline pic 1]

The `for each` loop loops through the a1 parameter.  Set the Items property to this:

```
@pipeline().parameters.a1
```

Within the `for each` loop, add an `if` condition:

[image: ADF pipeline pic 2]

Set the `if` condition to use the contains function to check the a2 parameter for the present of the current item in the `for each` loop ( ie `item()` ):

```
@contains(pipeline().parameters.a2,item())
```

Finally add an 'if false' activity, with an Append variable task, eg

[image: ADF pipeline pic 3]

`a3` is a variable of type Array.

[image: ADF pipeline pic 4]

No need to spin up a Spark cluster to solve this particular problem just yet ; )

Comment: I tested this with a 100 item and it seemed to work ok.   I'd be tempted to pass this off to some compute (like SQL, Batch or Databricks) if I already had that in the pipeline.

Comment: there' a "union" ability in data flow, will that solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the Filter activity.

In my case I'm working with 2 list of files, and loading the difference

```
ListA = [1,2,3,4,5]
ListB = [1,2,3]
ListA - ListB = [4,5]
```

Using the Filter Activity:

```
Items Box : @variables('ListB')

Condition Box : @not(contains(variables('ListA'),item()))
```

[This is a pipeline preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Awp.png)

[Filter Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyiWN.png)

[Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXBIA.png)

[Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkf7v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try solving this with a Join transformation in ADF Mapping Data Flows?

Comment: Data Flow is still in preview stage. My data is in SQL MI, which is currently not available in Data Flow.

Comment: If the data is in SQL, can you describe in in that format please?  Is it in a table, is it all in one column, or multiple columns?  It's not really clear from your description.

Comment: We're bringing SQL MI to Data Flows natively soon ... In the meantime, can you land your SQL MI data into Blob Store as Parquet using Copy Activity, so that you can access it in Data Flows? Parquet will maintain the data's schema.