# Modify output of an acitivity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: string, azure, azure-data-factory, transformation

I want to do a simple string transformation on the output of an activity in Azure Data Factory. I can use a Databricks notebook of course for that, but I would like to have a simpler and lighter solution. Is there any built in activity in Azure Data Factory specifically for this purpose?

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of what you want to do, ideally with sample data and expected outcome please?  ADF has some built-in functions which might help but I often find myself passing things off to other compute to do more complex things, like using a Stored Proc task, notebook (as you mentioned) or maybe Mapping Data Flows if a low-code approach is required.

Comment: I just want to replace a few characters in a string. Something you would normally do with the replace function in languages like Python and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of an active can't be modified or changed directly.

In Data Factory, if you want to achieve that, it will be complex. There isn't a simpler and lighter solution. Also, there isn't an exist built in activity in Azure Data Factory specifically for this purpose.

The Data Factory workarounds would like this:

1. Store the active output into a JSON file, then modify the JSON File through Data Flow. Some others have post the same question, you can search and found that. The step also is a little complex.
2. Pass the output into parameter or variable with Set variable. Then use the expression language/function to modify the output. The expression may be complex too.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory offers a limited number of [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#string-functions) for manipulating strings in the pipeline.  `concat`, `replace`, `split` and `substring` are some of the main ones which will allow you do things like this

- get the filename from a full filepath  (using `lastIndexOf with '\'`)
- get the extension from a full filepath (using `lastIndexOf with '.'`)
- basic find and replace operations (using `replace`)
- string concatenation (using `concat`)

In this example I have a variable named `varName` with the value of 'MetallicPriest'.  I use a **Set Variable** activity to *transform* that variable into another string.  Bonus point if you can tell me what that string is:

```
@replace(concat(substring(variables('varName'), 3, 2 ), substring(variables('varName'), 7, 3 ), substring(variables('varName'), 0, 1 ), replace(substring(variables('varName'), 10, 4 ),'e','') ), 'Pr', 'He')
```

There are also the [collection functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#collection-functions) like `split`, `join` and `union` which allows you to treat your strings like arrays and do some [interesting things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435952/collection-to-exclude-array-items-in-azure-data-factory).

I think it's missing some basic string functions like `reverse`, `stuff`, any kind of RegEx and you should note that the substring is 0-based (unlike SQL Server), but maybe you can come up with some *gold*.

Mapping Data Flows offers a wider array of string functions but if you already have compute available to your pipeline like SQL databases, Databricks, Azure Synapse Notebooks etc, use them as they offer much more powerful string manipulation.

Comment: Potentially some gold here for you @MetallicPriest, if you already have the base metals that is... lol